# Leverage OpenSSH ControlPersist via Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssh

I'd like to use OpenSSH's ControlPersist feature in a python tool to run arbitrary commands on remote nodes.

Is there any way to use the `ControlPath` socket OpenSSH creates when opening a connection to a node outside of just calling `ssh -oControlPath=/path/to/socket user@address <command>` multiple times with something like `Popen()`?

Before it gets suggested, I cannot use Paramiko for the environment where this will run.

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenSSH source code](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html) contains a file named ["PROTOCOL.mux"](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/PROTOCOL.mux) which describes the protocol used by the control-master feature.

In theory, any software package could implement the protocol and use a control socket. In practice, I've never heard of any other software which did that. It's likely that the only software implementing the protocol is the OpenSSH `ssh` utility, so the only way to use the feature is by invoking the `ssh` program.